# One page navigation blocking my content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to do a minimal version of the problem i am having. In short i am doing header with navigation that always sticks to the top of page when scrolling.

Now the problem is if you try and click on a section in the navigation, when you get scrolled to the section the navigation blocks half the content at the top by getting in the way.

This means the user has to scroll back up a little to see the content properly. I am using lorem ipsum as content replacement there.

How would i adjust where my browser position lands when the user clicks the navigation button so i can position the window correctly?

https://jsbin.com/hopiqe/edit?html,css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eli-

Using HTML/CSS only, you'd have to do a hack like Kommodore suggests to get this working properly. Your really need JS to do this right.

You can do this with jQuery and a little foresight:

```
  // Button 1 is what you click to start the interaction
  $(".button1").click(function() {
    // Using jQuery Animate and ScrollTop...
    $('html, body').animate({
        // We point user to div1
        // We have an offset from the top of the window minus 50px
        // `-50` should match the height of your header
        scrollTop: $("#div1").offset().top-50
    // 500 is milliseconds to do the `Animate` interaction
    }, 500); 
  });
```

You could also use a combination of jQuery plugins called [ScrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) and [LocalScroll](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.localScroll).

I wired up a working [CodePen](http://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/OyXOxr) that builds off the code you provided. The JS probably needs more tightening but you should get the idea.

Comment: No worries - glad I could help.

Comment: why wouldnt this work with html tag styled to "overflow: hidden" ?? I really like it when you dont get that white overflow when you scroll to the top or bottom. Your code seems to work fine when this is disabled but once its turned on, doesnt work anymore.

Comment: You shouldnt style the html tag directly. Make a container div and apply properties to that. Also - don't set a height on vertical elements with content like that. Let them flow naturally and you wont even need overflow:hidden;

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way should be adding another div as a placeholder with `height: 140px` in front of each div (which then has to be called instead of the div) or using `margin-top: 140px` for each div.

Comment: if i used margin top for each div that would ruin the look of the one page site if you were to scroll trough it without using the navigation. Same if i added a div, the design would have 140px height gaps. Not what im looking for.